# ¿Cómo rehacer filas y columnas para una base de datos?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, excel, tablas

Tengo una matriz de varios miles de datos con la siguiente estructura

| nombre | variable1 | variable2 | variable3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | 50 | 90 |
| b | 8 |  | 30 |
| c |  | 15 |  |

Y, para generar una base de datos normalizada, entiendo que debo transformarla al siguiente formato

| nombre | variable | valor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 10 |
| a | 2 | 50 |
| a | 3 | 90 |
| b | 1 | 8 |
| b | 3 | 30 |
| c | 2 | 15 |

He intentado hacerlo, sin éxito, utilizando la función `CROSSTAB` de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
'select nombre, variable1, variable2, variable3
 from tabla')
AS prueba(nombre text, variable text, valor int);
```

¿Cómo debería hacerse? Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Sí, claro... Con un simple `SELECT`, pero debes intentar algo para que podamos ayudarte :)

Comment: He editado la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería algo así:

```
SELECT nombre,1 variable,variable1 valor
  FROM tabla
  WHERE variable1 IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT nombre,2 variable,variable2
  FROM tabla
  WHERE variable2 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT nombre,3 variable,variable3
  FROM tabla
  WHERE variable3 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY nombre,variable;
```

Que da como resultado:

```
+--------+----------+-------+
| nombre | variable | valor |
+--------+----------+-------+
| a      |        1 |    10 |
| a      |        2 |    50 |
| a      |        3 |    90 |
| b      |        1 |     8 |
| b      |        3 |    30 |
| c      |        2 |    15 |
+--------+----------+-------+
```

A partir del dataset que propones:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla(
  nombre varchar(7),
  variable1 int,
  variable2 int,
  variable3 int
  );
INSERT INTO tabla (nombre, variable1, variable2, variable3) VALUES
('a',10,50,90),
('b',8,NULL,30),
('c',NULL,15,NULL);
```

Para crear todos los `UNION` suelo apoyarme en cualquier lenguaje de programación que me ayude a construir la consulta con un bucle. Espero que te resulte útil. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.